# Symmetricds Initial Load with Order by SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, symmetricds

I am trying to do an initial load of data based on order by `creationtime` column. My `sym_trigger_router` (for currencies table ) has below `initial_load_select` :-

```
initial_load_select = "1 = 1 order by t.CreationTime"
```

which create query as below :-

```
select count(*) 
from "board"."dbo"."currencies" t 
where 1=1 
order by t.CreationTime desc;
```

It works with MySQL but not with SQL Server because SQL Server does not support order by with `count(*)`.

I'm getting this error :

> [head-85711c60-84d5-4527-b31f-a861aa8caa9a] - JdbcSqlTemplate - SQL caused exception: [select count(*) from "board"."dbo"."currencies" t where 1=1 order by t.CreationTime desc ]
>
> java.sql.SQLException: Column "board.dbo.currencies.creationtime" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

As per this [link](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.9/html/user-guide.html#_initial_load_extract_in_background)

> When 0 is specified for initial_load_batch_count, SymmetricDS will
>   execute a count(*) query on the table during the extract process

but symmetricds 3.9 has [removed this column](https://www.symmetricds.org/issues/view.php?id=3092), now what is workaround to ignore `count(*)` query for SQL Server for initial load?

Any help?

Comment: That order by makes no logical sense, why should it be allowed? You are sorting groups of data where the individual values are not part of the group. If you had 6 values in the column what would the "order" be? MySql seems to allow some really bizarre stuff when it comes to aggregation. But what I am really confused on is what you are asking??

Comment: its initial load query it suppose to start loading data in store database in order by creation time else there will be number of database insertion issue. initial load query are like :- select * from table where 1=1 order by creationtime. but after symmetricds 3.9 it create first query as select count(*) and then it create select * query.  initial_load_select column has half query which act for filter and order the data.

Comment: If that was supposed to clear up your question it failed.

Comment: What are the insertion issues you are running into? If it's due to a foreign key, SymmetricDS should order the insertions accordingly. Is there some type of assumed foreign key that doesn't exist on the db? You can always manually order the initial loads.

Comment: i would like to describe one of the problem:- i have all the id as UUID, and i have table called group and its has composite relationship, so its like group  table and parent_group key which belongs to same table. in this case i need order by to load the data. so parent will be insert first then child group will insert after it. But same query is working in MySQL then Symmetric should have check to avoid unsupported MSSQL query. Like because query like above not work with MSSQL. In this case my symmetric configuration are not general.